# [Realm/React-Native debugger]: constructor must be of type 'function', got (undefined)

Tags: react-native, realm

It is working as well without debugger mode. But on debugger mode, I am getting error when try to create Realm object with schema parameters.

```
import Realm from 'realm';

class Todo extends Realm.Object {}
Todo.schema = {
    name: 'Todo',
    properties: {
        done: {type: 'bool', default: false},
        text: 'string',
    },
};

class TodoList extends Realm.Object {}
TodoList.schema = {
    name: 'TodoList',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        creationDate: 'date',
        items: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Todo'},
    },
};

export default new Realm({schema: [Todo, TodoList]});
```

Realm JS SDK Version: 2.17.0
React Native: 0.57.1

[constructor must be of type 'function', got (undefined)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO0JI.png)

Comment: Can you add relevant code for your React Component? Wherever it is that you do `import React, {Component} from 'react';`

Comment: Yes it already has in all components @LuisRizo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error only appears in version `2.18.0`([latest](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/)) try downgrading to the version [before](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/2.16.0/) `2.16.0`

To downgrade the realm package

```
npm uninstall realm

npm install --save realm@2.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is related from 2.18.0 version of realm. You should downgrade to 2.16.0 or upgrade.
And dont forgot to check version number on package.json. It should be "realm": "2.16.0" not "realm": "ˆ2.16.0". I lost 1 day for that

After that, run this code for reset all packages;
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install && yarn start -- --reset-cache